# Firebase API doesn't respond with common error codes using Axios on react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-redux, axios

I'm working with Firebase Auth REST API and React Native using Axios and Redux.

I have an action to Sign in with email and password, this is my code:

```
export function signIn(data){
    const request = axios({
        method:'POST',
        url:SIGNIN, 
        data:{
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
            returnSecureToken:true 
        },
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
        }).then(response => {
            return response.data
        }).catch( e => {
            console.log(e)
            return false
        });

    return {
        type: SIGN_IN_USER,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

If I insert a credentials with email and password correctly everything is fine.

But if I insert an email with errors I expect an answer as indicated in the documentation by example:

> EMAIL_NOT_FOUND: There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.
>
> INVALID_PASSWORD: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
>
> USER_DISABLED: The user account has been disabled by an administrator.

But I only receive this answer if I generate some error:

> Error: Request failed with status code 400

Nothing like the answers indicated in the documentation.

Can somebody help me? Thanks!!

Comment: 400 means bad request you probably send malformed data. Or maybe you're using old library and firebase updated the API. Just a guess.

Comment: @jcubic But when I make the request with the correct email and password everything is fine. When entering the request with the wrong credentials I expect some error but it always tells me the code 400. I want to think that if the request was wrong when entering the correct credentials I would not have to access it correctly.

Comment: Oh, you need to handle 400 error then, nothing you can do about it if it work with correct password and return 400 or wrong one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution:

console.log(error.response.data.error.message)

Comment: I love you!  Finally I find a solution

Comment: omg why was this not obvious, this shouold be added to the firebase docs

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution finally, just check how you have imported your `firebaseConfig.js` where you have initialize your firebase.

Most of the case we export default firebaseConfig and import it as a object:

```
import { firebaseConfig } from './src/config/FirebaseConfig'; // Incorrect
import FirebaseConfig from './src/config/FirebaseConfig'; // Correct Order
```

Comment: Is that instead of using axios then?