# Firebase REST API doesn't respond with common error codes using Fetch API on React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, rest, fetch

There were similar discussion here [Firebase API doesn't respond with common error codes using Axios on react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463153/firebase-api-doesnt-respond-with-common-error-codes-using-axios-on-react-native), but guy was using Axios. I would like to use Fetch API, and hope there are similar solution using this API for current case.

The issue is when I get error from Firebase REST API statusText of response is empty. I only got status code.

If I will make same request with the same url and options using Axios  I will get error description which defied by Firebase API (like TOKEN_EXPIRED, USER_DISABLED, USER_NOT_FOUND, INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN, MISSING_REFRESH_TOKEN etc.) using `console.log(error.response.data.error.message)`

How I can achieve same output with Fetch API?

```
 const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: bodyString
    });

if (response.ok) {
    const payload = await response.json();
    return payload as HttpResponse;
} else {
    throw new Error(`Server error: ${response.statusText}. Status: ${response.status}`);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following: 1) What is the status code you get back? 2) What is the value of `url`? 3) What is the value of `bodyString`?

Comment: `await response.text()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the actual error from express instead of status 500 in React on failed fetch in POST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67783798/283366)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the ticket to make it more clear, but doesn't matter what is value of url and bodyString. The point is I expect to get an error, but with description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I missed to check this.
The solution: `await response.text()`